# How to find the auto-created service connection when deploying to AKS

Tags: azure-devops, pipeline, azure-aks, serviceconnection

During a pipeline run, under deployment job, providing a deployment environment eliminates the need of providing service connection manually. I'd guess, it's either creating a new SC at this time or it would have created SC at the time of environment creation and using the same.
Either ways, is there a way to find out which Service connection is being used from the logs of pipeline run or from anywhere else?
In our environment, I see a lot of service connection for one environment and a cleanup is necessary to get things in place.

I tried giving SC manually along with environment and it works as expected. So, going forward, I can use this method. But for cleanup, I'd still like to know which one gets used when not specified! (none of the auto-created SCs show any execution history, but I know the deployment has happened multiple times)

Comment: Hi there, have you got a chance to check my answer below? Hope it could be helpful to resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

As a Kubernetes resource in an environment is referencing Kubernetes service connection, you can use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/kubernetes/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0) to list the `serviceEndpointId` of a Kubernetes resource, which is also the `resourceId` of the referenced service connection.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environmentId}/providers/kubernetes/{resourceId}?api-version=7.0
```

Applied with the value of the `serviceEndpointId` from the response of the above API, we can proceed to use this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/serviceendpoint/endpoints/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) to get the referenced service connection details.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/serviceendpoint/endpoints/{endpointId}?api-version=7.0
```